# Install ubuntu 12.x

Tags: 12.04, installation

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 in my 64bit windows 7 laptop. I decided to get rid of windows 7 and want to have only ubuntu in my laptop, so would you please give me a clear instructions that I have to follow to install ubuntu?
btw, which ubuntu ( 12.04 or 12.1) is more stable?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 12.04 is a so called LTS (**L**ong **T**erm **S**upport) release, so if you don't want to update every 6 months your should use 12.04. 12.04 should also be more stable than 12.10.

If you want to completely erase Windows 7 you only need to download an installation image at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and burn the image to a CD and boot your machine from that CD.

The rest of the installer should be self-explanatory. When you're asked if your want to delete the Windows partition just answer yes.

Comment: Thank you for. Just to make it clear, my laptop has windows 7 and ubuntu side by side ( dual boot). So, it has seven partitions. Now, I want to erase these partitions and install ubuntu 12.04 only. Should I first un-install ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: If you don't need the data from Ubuntu anymore or have it backed up somewhere else you can just overwrite it.

Comment: thank u. I tried to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS using the erase disk and install option. It was working perfectly and installing files as well, but at the end it crushed down and says some problems with the disk. Is this common?? What should I do please?

Comment: That's not common at all, but pretty hard to analyse without sitting in front of the machine. By "the disk" you mean the harddrive or the CD?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use disk utility to delete the W7 partition and then resize your partitions from your installation, like fotomonster said if your install is the 12.04 you can use my method and you already have a good OS, if you want to install 12.10 backup your files, then download the image and install, and in the installer you can select the use entire disk option, then restore your files ;)

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Before asking read the Ubuntu Help

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation